# sliding window for linear regression using numpy as_strided

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I have leveraged the rolling window examples using as_strided to create various sliding versions of numpy functions.

```
def std(a,window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.std(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape,strides=strides),axis=1)
```

Now I'm attempt to leverage the same as_strided method on a linear regression function. y = a + bx

```
def linear_regress(x,y):
  sum_x = np.sum(x)
  sum_y = np.sum(y)
  sum_xy = np.sum(np.multiply(x,y))
  sum_xx = np.sum(np.multiply(x,x))
  sum_yy = np.sum(np.multiply(y,y))
  number_of_records = len(x)
  A = (sum_y*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_xy)/(number_of_records*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_x)
  B = (number_of_records*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/(number_of_records*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_x)
  return A + B*number_of_records
```

You can get the same result using stats

```
from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,p)
xValue = len(x)
y = (slope + intercept*xValue)
```

I am not sure how to fit the above functions into the as_strided method when two arrays are passed.  I guess I would have to create two shapes and pass both through?

```
def rolling_lr(x,y,window):
   shape = y.shape[:-1] + (y.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
   strides = y.strides + (y.strides[-1],)
   return linear_regress(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x,y shape=shape, strides=strides))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend using `skimage.util.view_as_windows` for rolling windows.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I have never seen the stride function. The docs do warn about this method however. An alternative method would be using linear algebra to do the regression on the windows. Here is a trivial example:

```
from numpy import *

# generate points
N            = 30
x            = linspace(0, 10, N)[:, None]
X            = ones((N, 1)) * x
Y            = X * array([1, 30])  + random.randn(*X.shape)*1e-1
XX           = concatenate((ones((N,1)), X), axis = 1)

# window data
windowLength = 10
windows = array([roll(\
          XX, -i * windowLength, axis = 0)[:windowLength, :]\
           for i in range(len(XX) - windowLength)])
windowsY = array([roll(Y, -i * windowLength, axis = 0)[:windowLength, :]\
           for i in range(len(Y) - windowLength)])


# linear regression on windows
reg = array([\
              ((linalg.pinv(wx.T.dot(wx))).dot(wx.T)).dot(wy) for \
                wx, wy in zip(windows, windowsY)])

# plot regression on windows
from matplotlib import style
style.use('seaborn-poster')
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, cm
fig, ax = subplots()

colors = cm.tab20(linspace(0, 1, len(windows)))
for win, color, coeffs, yi in zip(windows, colors, reg, windowsY):

    ax.plot(win, yi,'.', alpha = .5, color = color)
    ax.plot(win[:, 1], win.dot(coeffs), alpha = .5, color = color)
    x += 1
ax.set(**dict(xlabel = 'x', ylabel = 'y'))
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: thanks Global.  I use as_strided for the speed.  I have read the potential issues with using as_strided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with.  Not the prettiest but works.

```
def linear_regress(x,y,window):
    x_shape = x.shape[:-1] + (x.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    x_strides = x.strides + (x.strides[-1],)
    y_shape = y.shape[:-1] + (y.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    y_strides = y.strides + (y.strides[-1],)
    sx = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x,shape=x_shape, strides=x_strides)
    sy = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(y,shape=y_shape, strides=y_strides)
    sum_x = np.sum(sx,axis=1)
    sum_y = np.sum(sy,axis=1)
    sum_xy = np.sum(np.multiply(sx,sy),axis=1)
    sum_xx = np.sum(np.multiply(sx,sx),axis=1)
    sum_yy = np.sum(np.multiply(sy,sy),axis=1)
    m = (sum_y*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_xy)/(window*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_x)
    b = (window*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/(window*sum_xx - sum_x*sum_x)
```